# On beta sites, the monospace formatting in a spoiler quote is evil.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spoilers

It doesn't reproduce on Meta, but it will on any beta site.  To see an example, check out [this meta.chess post](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/122/86):

> [image]

Edit:

I noticed that on SciFi, English, Area 51, and Electrical Engineering (at least - those are the only ones I've tried), spoilers with monospace will show the monospace part whether or not the mouse is hovering over the block (though the normal font will continue to operate normally).  On those sites, however, it hasn't yet joined the Dark Side.

Comment: [Also recently reported on meta.codegolf.SE.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/809/inline-code-inside-a-spoiler-block-is-difficult-to-read)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I removed the background styling for `<code>` elements inside spoilers, so now they should match the normal "code inside a blockquote" styling and look much less evil as of the next build:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It's a bug in the `all.css` file used for formatting the page. In the file (which is missing several *thousand* carriage returns), the style for a spoiler code on hover is

```
.spoiler:hover code{color:#222;background-color:#444}
```

Someone a SE needs to change it to

```
.spoiler:hover code{color:#222;background-color:#eee}
```

*Voila*! Problem solved.

[image: fixed spoiler]

If you want to, you can manually edit inside Dev tools in your browser, but  it would be easier for the SE devs to change it. (*ahem*)

Comment: By the way, 'quote' is a weird color because I was messing with the CSS.

Comment: BTW, carriage return are removed to reduce byte count and optimize loading time.

Comment: As @nhahtdh said CSS files are generally shrunk down to one line for optimization, however some dev tools like what are in chrome can be set to display them back in a more readable manner with a pretty print option