# On MSE, the monospace formatting in a spoiler quote is evil

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, spoilers

[Remember this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136589/on-beta-sites-the-monospace-formatting-in-a-spoiler-quote-is-evil)

> Well, `it's back`!

([cf. screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCfuM.png))

I'll grant that MSE probably does not have as much use for spoiler quotes as, say, CodeGolf.SE, but there are still some posts that use it, e.g. [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109802/224428). Can we have [the same fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228441/224428) deployed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be working okay now; if for some reason it crops up again, let us know.