# Special character in spoiler text does not fade in or out

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Spoiler text is invisible until the user mouses over the spoiler box, at which point it appears. This uses a fade-in animation, and there is likewise a fade-out animation when the cursor leaves the spoiler text box. In [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26089) on Code Golf, however, the answer includes this spoiler:

> It just prints a `√` character in front of the number entered.

There is a `<code>` section in the spoiler, and this portion of the text does not fade in or out: it simply appears when the cursor enters the box and disappears when the cursor leaves it. This is a minor issue but I would regard it as a bug.

Comment: My example spoiler is also showing an ugly dark gray  background, which is caused by [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136589/on-beta-sites-the-monospace-formatting-in-a-spoiler-quote-is-evil?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in rev. 2014.4.21.2178, along with the background color issue you pointed out in the comments.

Comment: When will the fix be propagated to [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)? A **lot** of spoilers are used here and a **lot** of them have code blocks in them. [Example here.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/31836)

Comment: @ADTC Hrm, I thought it applied there as well. I'll look into it.